# How do I delete dynamically created elements in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm trying to figure out a way to delete dynamically created elements in my program. I can currently add a pattern above or below the current one.

What I am trying to do though, is to add a delete button right beside the two rows of squares, and then once the user clicks on that button, the particular pattern is removed and all other patterns move into proper positions.

What I have done so far:

```
var id_num = 1;
var picker = null;
$(function () {
$(document).on('click', ".repeat", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $self = $(this);
    var $parent = $self.parent();
    if($self.hasClass("add-bottom")){
      $parent.after($parent.clone(true).attr("id", "repeatable" + id_num));
      id_num = id_num + 1;
      //picker = null;

    } else {
      $parent.before($parent.clone(true).attr("id", "repeatable" + id_num));
      id_num = id_num + 1;
      //picker = null;
    }
});   
});
```

Any help or feedback is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the delete button inside a container and use it to delete.
Can be easy to move the button where you want.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QKgBzP

```
var id_num = 1;
var picker = null;
$(function () {
$(document).on('click', ".repeat", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $self = $(this);
    var $parent = $self.parent();
    var newobj=$parent.clone(true).attr("id", "repeatable" + id_num);
    if($self.hasClass("add-bottom")){
      $parent.after(newobj);
      id_num = id_num + 1;
      //picker = null;

    } else {
      $parent.before(newobj);
      id_num = id_num + 1;
      //picker = null;
    }
    newobj.append("<button class=\"remove\"> Remove</remove>");
});   
$(document).on('click', ".remove", function (e) {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
});
```

Comment: Do you know how I can make the delete button appear beside the two rows of squares?

Comment: You would most likely have to add classes to/for the dynamically generated content. Jquery would make that easier. `$( "yourElem" ).addClass( "newClass" );` Just rope that in with your creation of the button.

Comment: @blazerix this is a style problem and you have to design it ignoring the js. This is a quick example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QKgBzP but it is be better to review the html struct

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the parent of the button and force a remove:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("yourid");
    elem.parentElement.removeChild(elem);
```

On creation of another `repeatableX`, you would also be creating a button just for that container I assume.

On that button click you would look at the parent ID for the button, in your case, `repeatableX`, then tell it to remove that parent, something similar to the above snippet.

Comment: Tobia's answer is more complete, go with his.

Comment: I know stackoverflow advises against off-topic posts...but thanks for the response!